Typescript - Infering Rtk query hook returned data type
I am creating a function "useGetPreviousPeriodData" that takes as argument a list of query functions, and returns a list of same length containing the returned data of those input functions.
For this specific case the query functions are Rtk query hooks. So the input functions types are well defined.
I didn't manage to have useGetPreviousPeriodData infer the type of its return.
type AnyQueryDefinition<T = any> = QueryDefinition<any, any, any, T[], 'api'>; // I want to infer this T type

function useGetPreviousPeriodData(
  queryParams: QueryParams,
  queries: UseQuery<AnyQueryDefinition>[],
  trigger: boolean,
) {
  if (!queryParams.baseQueryParams.startDate || !queryParams.baseQueryParams.endDate) return;

  const previousPeriod = useMemo(() => {
    const startDate = new Date(queryParams.baseQueryParams.startDate!);
    const endDate = new Date(queryParams.baseQueryParams.endDate!);
    const diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    const previousStartDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() - diff);
    const previousEndDate = new Date(endDate.getTime() - diff);
    return {
      startDate: previousStartDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
      endDate: previousEndDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
    };
  }, [queryParams]);

  const newQueryParams = { ...queryParams, baseQueryParams: { ...queryParams.baseQueryParams, ...previousPeriod } };


  const queryResults = queries.map((query) => {
    const res = query(newQueryParams, { skip: !trigger });
    return res.data || [];
  });

  return queryResults;
}

The caller
  const queries = [
    useGetAssetsFootprintQuery,
    useGetResaledAssetsQuery,
    useGetReusedAndRepairedAssetsQuery,
    useGetReusedAndGiftedAssetsQuery,
  ];

  const previousPeriodQueries = useGetPreviousPeriodData(queryParams, queries, doneFetching);

previousPeriodQueries have the following type inferred (obviously as the default generic type is any):
const previousPeriodQueries: any[][] | undefined 
I tried updating the function definition to add a generic:
function useGetPreviousPeriodData<T>(
  queryParams: QueryParams,
  queries: UseQuery<AnyQueryDefinition<T>>[],
  trigger: boolean,
) {

But it results in the following inferred type:
const previousPeriodQueries: GetAssetsFootprint[][] | undefined 
GetAssetsFootprint being the returned data type of useGetAssetsFootprintQuery.
I want instead that returned array element type to be the type of the returned data of the corresponding query function in the input array
